# Chef Server 12 - What is the default password for admin user in chef server 12?

Tags: chef-infra

What is the default password for admin user in chef server 12?[image]

Comment: When I tried to create a user, "admin". Chef server returned me an error - saying the user already exist. That's why I was wondering what was the default password of admin.

Comment: Oh come on.. 2 negative ratings!!!!. people who come from chef 11. would certainly get that confusion!!!

Comment: I've just installed the chef automate official azure VM and here I am googling for default chef admin password so +1 to you Dinesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no longer a default user. You'll need to create one from the server command line using `chef-server-ctl`. You can find information on this in the Chef Server install documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Type the below command on Chef Server

```
chef-server-ctl user-create <username> <FirstName> <LastName> <emailid> 'password'
```

example:

```
chef-server-ctl user-create sam Samual Gons sam.gons@gmail.com 'LearnChef'
```